# Initialize object in initializer list

Tags: c++

I have a `class Foo` where I need to initialize a reference to another class, but first I need to get some reference interfaces from another classes.

This is just a dummy code to explain a bit better my **two questions**:

```
class Foo
{
public:
  Foo();
  ~Foo();
private:
  int m_number;
  OtherClass& m_foo;
};

Foo::Foo() :
  m_number(10)
{
  // I really need to do this get's
  Class1& c1 = Singleton::getC1();
  Class2& c2 = c1.getC2();
  Class3& c3 = c2.getC3();

  //How can I put the m_foo initialization in the initialization list?
  m_foo(c3);
}
```

The questions are:

**1 -** I need to retrieve all those references above, before I initialize my member `m_foo`. But I would like to initialize the `m_foo` on the initialization list. What's the nicest way to accomplish that without having that in a single line.
Is there any way?

**2 -** By doing the code above, I get the error:

```
error: uninitialized reference member 'OtherClass::m_foo' [-fpermissive]
```

Because I'm initializing with the parentheses as it would be done in the initialization list. How can I initialize then the `m_foo` properly?

Comment: Does `c1`, `c2` and `c3` get used for anything else?

Comment: @NathanOliver: I think the OP was pretty clear about this: Yes! "I really need to do this get's"

Comment: @Waggili Where?  All he states is he needs them before he initializes `m_foo`

Comment: @waas1919 you're talking about [member initializer lists](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list) not [`initializer_list`s](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list), I'd suggest modifying your title to make that clear.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may use delegating constructors (since C++11):

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo() : Foo(Singleton::getC1()) {}

private:

    explicit Foo(Class1& c1) : Foo(c1, c1.getC2()) {}
    Foo(Class1& c1, Class2& c2) : Foo(c1, c2, c2.getC3()) {}
    Foo(Class1& c1, Class2& c2, Class3& c3) : m_number(10), m_foo(c3)
    {
        // other stuff with C1, c2, c3
    }
    // ...
};
```